# Is there a special value for $\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, constants

The answer to an integral involved $\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}$, but I am stuck trying to find this number - either to a couple decimal places or exact value.

In general the logarithmic deriative of the zeta function is the [dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Examples) of the van Mangolt function:

$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \Lambda(n) n^{-s}  $$

Let's cheat: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=riemannzeta%27%282%29%2Friemannzeta%282%29) evaluates this formula as:

$$ \frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)} = - 12 \log A + \gamma + \log 2 + \log \pi \tag{$\ast$}$$

This formula features some interesting constants:

- $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant) constant     1.2824271291006226368753425688697...
- $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) constant 0.577215664901532860606512090082...
- $\pi$ is of course [3.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi)...

Wikipedia even says that $A$ and $\pi$ are defined in similar ways...  which is an interesting philosophical point.

---

Do we have a chance of deriving $(\ast)$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By differentiating both sides of the [functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation)$$ \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{\pi}(2 \pi)^{s} \sin \left( \frac{\pi s}{s} \right) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s),$$ we can evaluate $\zeta'(2)$ in terms of $\zeta'(-1)$ and then use the fact that a common way to define the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html) is $\log A = \frac{1}{12} - \zeta'(-1)$.

Differentiating both sides of the functional equation, we get

$$\begin{align} \zeta'(s) &= \frac{1}{\pi} \log(2 \pi)(2 \pi)^{s} \sin \left( \frac{\pi s}{2} \right) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s) + \frac{1}{2} (2 \pi)^{s} \cos \left(\frac{\pi s}{2} \right) \Gamma(1-s) \zeta(1-s)\\ &- \frac{1}{\pi}(2 \pi)^{s} \sin \left(\frac{\pi s}{2} \right)\Gamma^{'}(1-s) \zeta(1-s) - \frac{1}{\pi}(2 \pi)^{s} \sin \left(\frac{\pi s}{2} \right)\Gamma(1-s) \zeta'(1-s). \end{align}$$

Then letting $s =-1$, we get $$\zeta'(-1) =  -\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}}\log(2 \pi)\zeta(2) + 0 + \frac{1}{2 \pi^{2}}(1- \gamma)\ \zeta(2) + \frac{1}{2 \pi^{2}}\zeta'(2)$$ since $\Gamma'(2) = \Gamma(2) \psi(2) = \psi(2) = \psi(1) + 1 = -\gamma +1. \tag{1}$

Solving for $\zeta'(2)$,

$$ \begin{align} \zeta'(2) &= 2 \pi^{2} \zeta'(-1) + \zeta(2)\left(\log(2 \pi)+ \gamma -1\right) \\ &= 2 \pi^{2} \left(\frac{1}{12} - \log (A) \right) + \zeta(2)\left(\log(2 \pi)+ \gamma -1\right) \\ &= \zeta(2) - 12 \zeta(2) \log(A)+ \zeta(2) \left(\log(2 \pi)+ \gamma -1\right) \tag{2} \\ &= \zeta(2) \left(-12 \log(A) + \gamma + \log(2 \pi) \right). \end{align}$$

$(1)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

$(2)$ [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2)

**EDIT**:

If you want to show that indeed $$\zeta'(-1)= \frac{1}{12}- \lim_{m \to \infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{m} k \log k - \left(\frac{m^{2}}{2}+\frac{m}{2} + \frac{1}{12} \right) \log m + \frac{m^{2}}{4} \right) = \frac{1}{12}- \log(A),$$ you could differentiate the representation $$\zeta(s) =  \lim_{m \to \infty} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{m} k^{-s} - \frac{m^{1-s}}{1-s} - \frac{m^{-s}}{2} + \frac{sm^{-s-1}}{12} \right) \ , \ \text{Re}(s) >-3. $$

This representation can be derived by applying the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) to $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} {k^{-s}}$.

Comment: Why do we consider $\zeta'(-1)$ when we have $ \zeta'(2)$. I mean $\zeta'(2)$ is better to consider, because of the series and integral representations.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai The Glaisher–Kinkelin constant is frequently defined in terms of $\zeta'(-1)$. And the functional equation of the Riemann zeta function provides a way to relate $\zeta'(2)$ to $\zeta'(-1)$, thus showing how $\zeta'(2)$ is related to $A$.