# Evaluate the sum or asymptotic expansion of $\sum_{p\ge 3} \frac{\log \left({p}\right)}{{p}^{2} - 1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, asymptotics

In my research I cam across this sum

$$S = \sum_{p\ge 3} \frac{\log \left({p}\right)}{{p}^{2} - 1}$$

where $p$ is a prime number.  Numerical evaluation of the first $10^8$ primes yields $S = 0.338911932\cdots$.  So far I have not found anything concerning this sum in the literature.  I am looking for an analytical expression (sum over Möbius function?) and its asymptotic expansion if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this constant has an exact expression in terms of the Riemann zeta function
$$
\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \prod_p ( 1-p^{-s} )^{-1}. \quad(s>1)
$$
We have
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} &= -\frac d{ds} \log\zeta(s) \\
&= -\frac d{ds} \sum _p \log \bigl( ( 1-p^{-s} )^{-1} \bigr) \\
&= \sum_p \frac{\log p}{p^s-1}.
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$
-\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)} = \sum_p \frac{\log p}{p^2-1} = S + \frac{\log2}{2^2-1},
$$
and therefore
$$
S = -\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)} - \frac{\log2}3 = -\frac{6\zeta'(2)}{\pi^2} - \frac{\log2}3 \approx 0.33891193290788436993.
$$

Comment: using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1577823/583016), we can re-write this as $$S=\log\frac{A^{12}}{2^{4/3}\pi}-\gamma,$$ where $A$ is the Glaisher constant and $\gamma$ is the Euler constant